# Remove immediate newlines

Tags: jquery, regex, comments, newline, nodes

I have a pretty bad formatted output after removing comment lines.

I'd like to remove the newlines that remained.

**HTML**

```
<html>




<div class="donottouch">
</div>


</html>
```

I'd like this to become

**Wanted Output**

```
<html>
<div class="donottouch">
</div>
</html>
```

Without entering the other divs.

Code I use to remove comment lines:

```
$('> *', $content).contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 8) {
        $(this).remove()
    }
});
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You don't gain/lose anything really…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [`jQuery.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) utilitiy:

**Description:**

> Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string. The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of the string, they are preserved.

**Example:**

*Remove the white spaces at the start and at the end of the string:*
`$.trim("    hello, how are you?    ");`

*Result:*
`"hello, how are you?"`